# Como executar um comando em JavaScript em todas as abas do navegador?

Tags: javascript, html, navegador-de-internet

Eu estou tentando fazer um projeto, mas para faze-lo eu preciso que uma função em JavaScript seja executada em todas as abas do navegador do usuário ao mesmo tempo. Há alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Explicação:**

Se as outras abas que estiverem abertas forem da sua página sim é possível, se não for é impossível já que o javascript da sua página não vai controlar todo o navegador do usuário, agora se as janelas que estiverem abertas forem da sua página você precisará saber trocar informações entre cliente e servidor, não é uma resposta com exemplos porque sua pergunta não é sobre um assunto mais específico mas é uma resposta clara.

**Conclusão:**

> Não é possível controlar o navegador completamente só com javascript

Comment: Ok, mto obrigado

Comment: Se a resposta responde a sua pergunta marque como resolvida "✅"